# Non-functional pip after Homebrew upgrade of Python

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, homebrew

After performing my latest Homebrew update of Python, `pip --version` produces the error

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling all of my Homebrew Pythons and reinstalling just `python`, but still get the same error. All knowledge of my virtualenv configuration seems to have vanished as well.

How do I get pip (and virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper) working again after upgrading Python?

Comment: Did you have `conda` (or `anaconda`) installed any time in the past?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Nope. I had additional Pythons, but ran `brew uninstall` on all of them. It sure looks like one of those is still connected to pip.

Comment: Where is python3.7 located? Can you do `which python3.7` and tell the path?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj There's no 3.7. I had (in addition to Apple's 2.7) Homebrew's (3.7) and 3.8. It looks like the latest Hombrew update was to 3.8, so the separate 3.8 became unnecessary. In any case, that's when trouble started. So I cleaned up by uninstalling all my Pythons and reinstalling just Python `brew install python`. Somehow pip still looks for 3.7, it seems.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj If I ` export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH` I can get `pip` working (20.0.2 for 3.8), but not `pip3` (same error).

Comment: Ok we can fix that. Can I know the path of a working python binary? We can just force that path in the pip file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217472/discussion-between-rahul-bharadwaj-and-orome).